# Does lock, Monitor, Mutex waste CPU cycles like SpinWait?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization

Recently I started learning Parallel Programming using Task Parallel Library in C# and I read that SpinLock wastes CPU cycles and keeps spinning till the lock is acquired. Also while comparing methods: Thread.Sleep and Thread.SpinUntil I found that Thread.sleep releases scheduler so that scheduler can schedule other threads.
Does this hold true for the lock, Monitor, Mutex, and Interlocked also?.
Does CLR allow the scheduler to schedule other threads when lock, Monitor, Mutex, Interlocked are waiting to enter inside the critical section?

Comment: *"releases scheduler"* is not a thing. "*Does CLR allow the scheduler to schedule other threads...*" yes. However its extremely difficult to answer this, as there is unusual use of terminology and its difficult to understand what you are actually asking or why

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand your question. I try it this way:

- SpinLock is special, because it does a "busy wait". Only to be used when you know that the thread would wait for a very short time, e.g. some CPU cycles.
- lock, Monitor and Mutex do not busy wait. These are the regular and most commonly used ways of thread synchronization.
- Interlocked doesn't lock at all. It's for so called "lock free synchronization", which is tricky and should rarely be used.

I don't know what you mean by the scheduler. Threads are running until they are locked somehow. Only one thread can get the same lock. When you create your own threads, they are scheduled by the OS (AFAIK). When you used thread pools, they are scheduled there.

Comment: Scheduler means when waiting give service to other threads from the thread pool e.g. I have 3 threads one thread is executing critical section of lock so it has acquired the lock.... Now at the same time thread 2 also wants to execute the critical section of code but has to wait because the code is currently under thread 1..... Now my question is :since thread 2 is waiting to enter critical section. Will cpu process thread 3 or in short will it context switch  to thread 3 or just like spin lock keep waiting till thread releases lock....

Comment: Threads do not keep a Core busy, except of SpinLock.

Comment: You could run into problems when you use thread pools and there is a limited number of threads. When the maximum number of threads is reached, no more threads are created, even when all threads a waiting. So threads do not keep a CPU core busy, but they may occupy a thread in a thread pool with a limited number of threads.